# Can a massive particle in AdS be dropped from the boundary?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

My question revolves around the geodesics of massive point particles in fixed background AdS spacetime. Expressed in global coordinates $(\tau,\rho,\Omega_{i})$, the metric of $AdS_{d+1}$ (actually its universal cover) is,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&ds^2 = \frac{1}{\cos^2\rho}\left(-d\tau^2+d\rho^2+\sin^2\rho d\Omega_{d-1}^2 \right) \\
&\tau\in\mathbb{R} \\
&\rho\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
A massive particle following a *radial* trajectory dropped from $\rho(\tau_0)=\rho_0$, will then follow an oscillatory geodesic,
\begin{equation}
\rho(\tau) = |\arcsin\left[\sin\rho_0\cos\left(\tau-\tau_0\right)\right]|
\end{equation}

What troubles me is the case of dropping the particle from the boundary, i.e. $\rho_0 \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$. The geodesic then becomes lightlike and the massive particle behaves like a massless particle. This cannot, of course, be valid.

So my question really is, *why can't we drop a massive particle from the boundary $\rho_0\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$ of AdS*?

Comment: How would you have a massive particle at the boundary to start with?